# How to get model field from string path in Django

Tags: django, django-1.8

I'm trying to get the field object from a filter like string in Django.

For example,

```
Sale.objects.filter(product__category__name='shoes')
```

Given model `Sale` and the string `"product__category__name"`, is it possible to get the field object for `Category.name`? (or to be more specific, the `verbose_name` of that field).

**UPDATE**

This is what i eventually came up with

```
from django.db.models.fields import FieldDoesNotExist

def find_field(model, lookup):
    lookups = list(reversed(lookup.split("__")))
    field = None

    while model and lookups:
        current = lookups.pop()
        field = model._meta.get_field(current)
        model = field.related_model
        if lookups and model is None:
            raise FieldDoesNotExist(lookup)
    return field
```

Comment: Fine solution. Could you add it as one of the answers and accept so question will be marked as resoled?

Comment: Also does this work fine with m2m/genericrelations?

Answer (score 1):

To get a verbose_name you should call `object._meta.get_field('field').verbose_name`

```
category._meta.get_field('name').verbose_name
```

Comment: The point is getting to the category model from the lookup string.

Comment: Which objects do you have? `Sale` class and `"product__category__name"` string? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something along these lines

```
def get_verbose_name_from_query_string(query_string):
    query_string = query_string.split('__')[-1].split('_')
    model_name = query_string[0]
    field_name = query_string[1]
    model = apps.get_model('app_name', model_name)
    return model._meta.get_field(field_name).verbose_name

query_string = 'product__category_name'    
get_verbose_name_from_query_string(query_string)
```

This would return **Name**

If you have multiple apps this can get harder as you need to know the app name too, but maybe this can be passed in as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full solution on how to find the field from a lookup spanning relationships. This is based on the great answer that OP gave in the question, but with some improvements and bug fixes.

```py
from django.core.exceptions import FieldDoesNotExist
from django.db import models


def find_field_from_lookup(model_class: models.Model, lookup: str) -> models.Field:
    """Find field object from a lookup, which can span relationships.

    Example: `"book__author__name"` would return the `name` field of the `Author` model.

    Raises `FieldDoesNotExist` when the lookup is not valid.
    """
    field_names = list(reversed(lookup.split("__")))
    if not field_names or not model_class:
        raise FieldDoesNotExist(lookup)
    while model_class and field_names:
        field_name = field_names.pop()
        field = model_class._meta.get_field(field_name)
        model_class = field.related_model
        if field_names and not model_class:
            raise FieldDoesNotExist(lookup)
    return field
```